# JerseyInvocation expression not available in a class but reachable from Evaluate expression in IntelliJ debugger

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, request, jax-rs

I have a strange problem with Invocation interface from javax package. Namely, I want to test a header params which I am adding to get request to establish a connection with public API. My method responsible for adding a header to my request looks like:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
class ProductFacadeImpl implements ProductFacade {

  private NutritionixHeader nutritionixHeader;

  @Override
  public Invocation prepareHeaderForApiCall(String query) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget webTarget =
        client.target("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?query=" + query);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-id", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId());
    invocationBuilder.header("x-app-key", nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey());
    return invocationBuilder.buildGet();
  }
}
```

the test with JUnit 5 looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class ProductsFacadeImplTest {

  @Mock
  private NutritionixHeader nutritionixHeader;

  private ProductFacadeImpl productsFacade;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
    productsFacade = new ProductFacadeImpl(nutritionixHeader);
  }

  @Test
  void prepareHeaderForApiCall() {
    var query = "query";

    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId()).willReturn(x-app-id-param);
    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey()).willReturn(x-app-key-param);

    Invocation builder = productsFacade.prepareHeaderForApiCall(query);
    builder.invoke().getHeaders();

    then(nutritionixHeader).should(times(1)).getNutritionixAppId();

    assertEquals(builder.invoke().getStatus(), 200);
}
```

The problem occurs when I am evaluating a value from a line:

```
builder.invoke().getHeaders();
```

in the test with IntelliJ Expression Evaluator usage.

I am receiving an evaluation like:

[image: evaluation1]

As we can see there are no params like:

```
x-app-id
```

and

```
x-app-key
```

in the headers to create an assertion in my test.

On the other hand when we will try to evaluate an expression:

```
((JerseyInvocation) builder).requestContext.getHeaders()
```

we are receiving evalauation like below:

[image: debugger evaluation 2]

and this is a desirable response from header but unfortunately, I cannot use this expression

```
((JerseyInvocation) builder).requestContext.getHeaders()
```

in my code because IntelliJ cannot recognize the part requestContext with a message like:
[image]

I am a little bit confused about why my debugger can deal with the evaluation of the expression:

```
((JerseyInvocation) builder).requestContext.getHeaders()
```

but cannot deal with it in my class when I want to call this method on my own in the test.

I will be grateful for the suggestion of how to call this second method in my test to get a response looks like on the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's possible to evaluate private members during debugging. Solution for your problem is using `request()` method which returns `requestContext` instead 
 of accessing it directly.

https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyInvocation.java#L191